Erro na criação de Resource Group usando Terraform
Faala galera, de boa?
Eu fui designado a uma missão com terraform (estou aprendendo enquanto faço kkkk) e estou com um problema me tirando os cabelos. Pra contextualizar, eu criei um módulo e coloquei em um repo na Azure e esse módulo contém a criação de uma UAI, SQL Server, Database e um schedule job. A criação do Resource Group estou fazendo a partir do código da aplicação que usará o módulo, assim, consigo usar tfvars e mexer com vários ambientes.
Eis o meu problema, ao deixar o código completo contendo backend, provider, criação do resource group e o módulo, ele não cria o resource group, parte direto para o módulo e aponta o erro "A managed resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" has not been declared in module.job." Quando comento a linha do módulo ele interpreta a criação do resource group normalmente. Detalhe que o módulo e o código aplicação estão na mesma branch.
terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {
    storage_account_name = ""
    resource_group_name  = ""
    container_name       = ""
    key                  = ""
  }
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      version = ""
    }
    azuread = {
      version = ""
    }
    null = {
      version = ""
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  subscription_id = var.subscription
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "Rg-${var.environment}-${var.region_name}-Schedule-Job"
  location = var.region_code
}

### JOB ###

 module "job" {
   source                       = ""
   environment                  = var.environment
   region_code                  = var.region_code
   region_name                  = var.region_name
   subscription                 = var.subscription
   administrator_login          = var.administrator_login
   administrator_login_password = var.administrator_login_password
 }

Tentei usar depends_on
 module "job" {
   source                       = "git::/home/vsts/work/r1/a/tf-modules/.git//azure/tf-mssql-schedule-job-agent"
   environment                  = var.environment
   region_code                  = var.region_code
   region_name                  = var.region_name
   subscription                 = var.subscription
   administrator_login          = var.administrator_login
   administrator_login_password = var.administrator_login_password
   depends_on = [ azurerm_resource_group.rg. ]
 }

Tentei usar output e input
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "Rg-${var.environment}-${var.region_name}-Schedule-Job"
  location = var.region_code
}

output "resource_group_name" {
  value = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}

output "resource_group_location" {
  value = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
}

